# Unable to login to Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, login

I can't log in to my Fedora account. I see normal login screen, but after clicking on my name and entering correct password, screen goes black, nothing happens and after few seconds I am returned back to login screen without any changes.

In previous session I installed system updates and after restart this happens.

Does anybody knows hot to fix it?

I am using Fedora 19 x64.

Comment: can you drop to single user and check your keyboard language hasn't changed?

Comment: Care to share what fixed it?